# Activesheet.Name throws Out of Memory Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am receiving an

> Runtime Error 7, Out of Memory

on the line `Activesheet.Name = strName`
The strName is a valid sheet name (no special char).
I can manually rename sheet with no issues.

```
Sub MakeNewCompany(sht As String)
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : MakeNewCompany
' Author    : Kevin Waddle
' Purpose   : Make a copy of the Master Sheet named for the company
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Dim strName                         As String

strName = Replace(sht, " ", "")
If SheetExists(Replace(sht, " ", "")) Then
    MsgBox "There is already a sheet created for " & sht, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Already got some..."
Else
    Sheets("Master").Visible = True
    Sheets("Master").Select
    Sheets("Master").Copy After:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = strName
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = sht
    Sheets("Master").Visible = False
End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: this may sound trivial - but literally restart your computer and try again. If that doesn't help, do you have objects (shapes, activex, form controls) on your `Master` sheet?

Comment: Thank.Will try the restart.  There are shapes on the Master Sheet (Command Buttons), does that make a difference?

Comment: the shapes may make a difference. sometimes i have seem them cause issues when coping template sheets. you may have to work around that (but hopefully not)

Comment: Protip: dropping your email address on a website that gets scanned by a gazillion spam-bots every single day doesn't strike me as a good call. I've edited and flagged your post to get a moderator to redact the revisions that contain the email. Cheers!

Comment: Also keep in mind that there is a limit to the number of characters you can use in a sheet name. That limit is 30.

Comment: Restarting worked... Who knew...

Comment: Thanks for Protip and post edit... Didn't catch email in code